# How can I manually read N messages off the queue or if Y time has passed in the onmessage() method?

Tags: transactions, jms, mq

I am looking to implement the following logic in my Message driven beans onmessage method

Read N messages or wait for Y time, whichever happens first and then commit the transaction.

I would really appreciate if I can get a example of the code to implement this logic?

T

Answer (score 0):

Something like this code might be want you want to do.
Keep the listener to one single consumer though, no concurrent, load balanced onces, or this will get tricky. You probably want to inject the jms resources via annotations if you're on JEE6. The receive call will block wait for Y/N time if there is no

```
public void onMessage(Message msg) {

  // So we got a message, let's grab the JMS resources
  // Note that these could be injected as well, for convenience

  InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
  ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/connectionFactory");
  Destination destination = (Destination) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/myQueue");
  Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
  connection.start();
  MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
  Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  // TODO: handle msg here

  // So, let's start look for msgs.
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
      Message msg_i = consumer.receive(Y/N);
      // Handle msg_i here.
  }
  consumer.close();
  session.close();
  connection.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Petter. Will this approach work if I have multiple instances of MDB configured to listen to one queue. I am using EJB 3.0 specification along with activation spec. Is there a different way of handling in such case?

Comment: You can't really achieve that within the scope of one transaction. Then you would have to, also, use something like message groups to make sure messages aren't consumed in parallell from the same message group.

Comment: This will be rather complicated. What are you trying to achieve on a higher level? Perhaps it will be better to deal with this in the application logic somehow. MDB has it's nice upsides, but sharing state across different managed threads inside multiple transactions isn't one of them

Comment: We are expecting around 17 mil transactions per day. So we would like create a small unit of work that can then be batched. We have certain transformations to the data before storing it into the Database. Since we would like to reduce the frequent connections to the database, we are looking at batching the transactions.

Comment: So, the order, sequence or what messages get into which batch is not of importance? Then this solution might/should work, even for multiple MDB instances. I would setup some test cases for this, non the less.